# Cannot load video within webview of react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, webview, jsx

I'm not able to load a video which is fetching from a json data inside of `WebView` in react native. When I give a static url then I'm getting a video loading but there is no content. When I checked it with a youtube video it is coming. Please help me I'm stuck with this for days. Please. Following is my code:

**react code**

```
 fetch(GLOBAL.VIDEO_URL + this.props.navigation.state.params.id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) =>
                    this.setState({
                        section: responseData.data.video_url[0]

                    })

                );

<WebView
                            source={{ baseUrl: '', html: this.state.section }}
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        />
```

When I tried the above I'm getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/leyTH.png . But when I tried with a youtube url it is working fine. Following is the api I'm fetching from server.

**json**

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 8631,
        "post_title": "Video Unit 1",
        "post_content": "</p>\n",
        "vedio_url": [
            "https://indianeconomy-lms.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/what.mp4?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAISUKXIZNZMXWED5Q%2F20190131%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190131T100607Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=cbbc13281f92b771e6b10ae83fd9d18768caa63e9fe808c392bad71e8f610607"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1- use the conditions above webview like

```
this.state.section !== null && <WebView />
```

2- It seems youtube video is working fine because of youtube URL is accessible.
when you use the JSON object for getting the URL of videos so that URL need credentials for accessing the content.

https://indianeconomy-lms.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/what.mp4?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAISUKXIZNZMXWED5Q%2F20190131%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190131T100607Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=cbbc13281f92b771e6b10ae83fd9d18768caa63e9fe808c392bad71e8f610607

above URL giving the access Denied error that's the problem

Comment: It works fine when I give static url within `source` component.But when I give like this `<WebView
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                            domStorageEnabled={true}
                            source={{ baseUrl: '', html: this.state.section }}


                        />` I'm getting the above error.So how to give json data within webview?

Comment: please use the conditions above on webview and make sure the section is not null then render the webview when the section is url

Comment: I got result when I consoled `this.state.section`. The problem is when I tried to give the json data within `html` prop of `WebView`.Is there any other method?